# CSS3 - fast-forward keyframe animation to end on &:hover

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I have a *hitbox* that is basically a pulsating rectangle to indicate that you should click something and when I `:hover` the element I want to fast-forward the animation to it's end.

I've done a workaround, which is essentially adding a pseudo-element with the end-state of the element that has a beginning opacity of 0 that I simply transition to 1 on :hover.

My workaround on CodePen: http://codepen.io/KATT/pen/ziBsq

How can I achieve the similar result without using a pseudo-element?

Comment: Guess so you're looking for [**this**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/09/how-to-create-a-fast-hover-slideshow-with-css3/)

Comment: Can't see how? If you're talking about setting `animation-play-state` to `paused` it won't help me, it simply freezes the animation at it's current position. I want to move it to it's end.

Comment: I have tried to achieve this effect before.  The current state is this: interactive css-only animations are restricted to transitions, and non-interactive animations get to use animation keyframes. And they don't mix well. Nesting (pseudo) elements and effects, and triggering parent classes with javascript are the best ways to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not (currently) possible.

[daviestar summed it up quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041620/css3-fast-forward-keyframe-animation-to-end-on-hover#comment30075705_20041620):

> I have tried to achieve this effect before. The current state is this: interactive css-only animations are restricted to transitions, and non-interactive animations get to use animation keyframes. And they don't mix well. Nesting (pseudo) elements and effects, and triggering parent classes with javascript are the best ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the `animation-duration` and set the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` on `:hover`?

In this case, I've set the `animation-duration` to `0.1s` and by setting `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` it will persist the end state.

```
.hitbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
    animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    &:hover {
        animation: pulse 0.1s ease-in-out forwards;
    }
}
```

Comment: The animation duration gets lost somewhere along the way, see here, http://codepen.io/KATT/pen/LcvBb

Comment: I thought about changing `animation-duration-count` to `1`, but it doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Do you mean the animation-iteration-count?

Comment: I don't get what you want to fast-forward on hover. Do you want to fast-forward the pulsating effect?

Comment: @ChristoferVilander, ah yeah, of course I meant `animation-iteration-count`. Sorry. :)

Comment: @user2549787: the pulsating effect is an encouragement for the user to click somewhere. Whilst the user is *about* to click, i.e., hover I don't want it to pulsate. If you look at my example you might see why it might be desirable and has notable difference in the user experience.

Comment: @Alex OK :). But I'm not sure what you mean by "The animation duration gets lost somewhere along the way". Which browser are you using? I'm using Chrome (30.0.1599.101) and the example I provided seems to work as you wanted, provided that I've understood your question correct.

Comment: @ChristoferVilander: It doesn't transition when you hover, just snaps. Writing `animation: 0;` in `:hover` would effectively have the same effect. I'm on 31.0.1650.57.